# "A posteriori" estimates for finite difference methods

Tags: pde, finite-difference, error-estimation

Suppose I have a PDE in a rectangular domain that I am solving numerically via a finite difference method. How do I answer the question, "How fine do I need to make the grid to so that my solution is within $\epsilon$ of the true solution?" We can assume some basic interpolation scheme is used to fill in the points outside of the grid.

For a concrete example, we might consider solving a 2-d heat equation with Crank-Nicolson. But I'd like methods that apply more broadly.

My understanding is that for finite element methods, there is a well-developed theory of "a posteriori" estimates that answer my question. Does a theory providing rigorous error bounds exist for finite difference methods?

Comment: It may be useful for this to check out the Richardson extrapolation idea, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation

Comment: @MaximUmansky I may be mistaken, but my undestanding is that Richardson extrapolation will not offer full rigorous error bounds, because the error estimates it provides rely on unknown constants in the a priori bounds for the FD method. (I suppose one could in principle follow the proofs to find those constants, however, but I have never seen this done.)

Answer (score 3):

If the grid is fine enough, the numerical solution should depend on the grid spacing ℎ as $(ℎ)=_{}+ℎ^$ where there are three unknown parameters $_{}$, $$, $$ (the last one may be known *apriori* from the numerical algorithms used in the code). But even with three unknown parameters, with numerical solutions on three different grids, say with grid spacing $h$, $2h$, $4h$, you'll have three equations, that's enough to determine those three unknown parameters. After that, you'll know how small ℎ has to be to make the error $\epsilon=ℎ^$ smaller than the tolerance.

Comment: I think this is essentially Richardson extrapolation? I agree for practical purposes this is excellent. However I think it is not enough for fully rigorous control, because really we have $f(h) = f_{\mathrm{exact}} + A h^n + B h^m + \dots$ where $m > n$, so the unknown $B$ is still there an uncontrolled. It can only be a serious problem if it huge, but I do not know of a proof that it is not huge...

Comment: Yes, this is the Richardson extrapolation idea. For a fine enough grid, only the smallest exponent would matter.

Comment: Again, I agree in practice that is the case. However, I do not believe this method provides a rigorous and computable error guarantee, like a posterori methods do. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What posteriori methods are those? If you have in mind something specific, we should look at it and compare.

Comment: Consider the following estimate, which I found in Sergey Repin's "A Posteriori Estimates for Partial Differential Equations," chapter 3. Consider Poisson's equation $\Delta u + f = 0$ on some domain $\Omega$ with boundary condition identically $0$. For a Galerkin approximation $u_h$ to the true solution $u$, we have $\| \nabla( u - u_h) \| \le C \| \Delta u_h + f \|$. Here $C$ is a constant from Friedirchs inequality for $\Omega$, which is easy to determine explicitly. Hence we obtain a rigorous error estimate with no uncontrolled constants.